# Deitel Live Lessons C# 2008

Tags: c#, resources

I've been trying to gain a better understanding of C# through books but I tend to learn things quicker with someone explaining them to me.  Has anyone tried any of the Deitel live lessons DVD's, specifically the C# 2008 set?  Just wondering if anyone has any opinions on them.  Thanks!

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can really recommend the DVDs to you, i own them myself and they are really comprehensive and helped me understanding the fundamental principles of C# development when i was switching my preference from Delphi to C#.